# How to listen to a keep-alive HttpResponseMessage until it's closed?

Tags: c#, keep-alive, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` to send an asynchronous POST request to a remote web server. That remote web server responds with the Connection header set to `keep-alive`. Eventually, it will close the connection.

What I can't figure out how to do is keep receiving data until the connection is set to close.

For example, consider the following code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string requestUri = ...; //My GET uri
string content = ...; //url-encoded contents of the request

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, new StringContent(content));
```

In the code above, `response` will have the `Connection` header set to `keep-alive`. I couldn't find any members on [HttpResponseMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.aspx) that seem to give me any means of continuing to receive information after the first `keep-alive` is received.

**I can't figure out how to continue receiving responses until the Connection closes.**

I was able to find all sorts of resources that dealt with sending `keep-alive` requests. That's not my issue. My issue is in receiving/handling a `keep-alive` response from the server.

Please let me know if there is anymore information that I could provide to improve this question.

Comment: Not sure if I'm misunderstanding your question, but once you post the request and you get the response, the cycle (request/response) is complete, there is no more data to be received from the server.

Comment: @ManyRootsofAllEvil What you say is true. If the server responds with `Connection: keep-alive` that means the Connection from server to client is not closed yet. I need to continue receiving responses until the Connection is closed.

Comment: @crush Are you saying that you receive partial response to your original request? Or are you asking how to receive response from successive requests on the same connection?

Comment: @LB2 How can I continue receiving responses from the server until the server indicates the connection is closed? I would expect this functionality would actually lie on the `HttpClient`, but I cannot find a mechanism.

Comment: @crush The connection might not be closed but you have already the response. What else are you expecting to receive? You would need to send a new request to get more data. Keep-Alive is about multiple requests with the same connection. If you make another request you will not incurr the cost of a new connection. I don't understand what you are expecting to receive

Comment: @ManyRootsofAllEvil So should I send a GET request to the same URI until I get a response with a `Connection: close`? I was under the impression that the server would continue sending responses until it sent it's final response with `Connection: close`.

Comment: The server will not send more responses as there's nothing for it to respond to, once it's satisfied your request.

What makes you so worried about the connection being opened at the server?

Comment: @ManyRootsofAllEvil I guess I misunderstood the purpose of Keep-Alive. I was expecting more responses from the server, but I now see that the server was expecting me to send a request as follow-up to its response. Thanks for your patience. I learned something new. I wish I could give you some reputation for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Connection: keep-alive` purpose is not to enable server to send multiple responses for the same single request - this would fundamentally violate how HTTP works.

`Connection: keep-alive` is server's way of signaling to the client that client can submit next request using the same, already established, TCP connection, thus help avoid the costs of establishing new connection (and possibly TLS handshake as well).

Reuse of the connection is (typically) handled by underlying library, and is abstracted away such that user (as in developer) of the library need not worry about handling.

All you should be doing is keep making as many `client.Post/Get/etc` requests, and the `HttpClient` library will take care of managing the underlying TCP connection and its reuse.

There is one area in HTTP that may *look* counter to the above and thus confusing, but is not.  The case is when server returns HTTP Status `100 Continue`.  In this case you will see another response come from the server for still the same original request (and by "see" I mean not from `HttpClient`, but rather on the wire if you were to snoop with a tool like WireShark or a proxy).  What is happening in this case is if a client is making a large request, the server simply signals to the client that it is continuing to accept and read request, and for the client to continue sending that original request.  Once full request is received, the server will process and respond with a final response code and message.  And again, `HttpClient` will abstract away this interim `100 Continue` response, so as developer you need not worry about it (in most if not all cases).

Comment: Thanks for the expanded explanation. This question was born out of a misunderstanding of Keep-Alive and an oversight on my part.

Comment: @crush Thanks and I updated answer with additional quirk about status code `100` which may appear as opposite to what the answer says, but in actuality is not.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks for that tidbit of additional information. I always like to know what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is receive the response for a given request you don't need to deal with keep-alive at all. Keep-alive is purely a performance optimization. The framework transparently manages connections.

All you do is send a request and receive a response. There is exactly one response per request.

One side will eventually close the connection which is not of any concern to you. You don't notice any effect of that.

Comment: Thanks. This helps clear up the misunderstanding I had about Keep-Alive's significance.