# Keep and continually listen on an open http connection

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient, httpwebresponse, httpconnection

I have this service

https://srs-ds.i.daimler.com/STARCDS/services/Server?action=connect&id=GS0034837&version=1.4

if you actually open that url con chrome you see that the request "does not end", it gives and initial response and keeps open and reading continually (after about 5 minutes you will see a keep alive message ). I need to establish a connection with the same behavior from .net . I have used several approaches but nothing have worked yet.

What is the right way for opening that kind of connection and be hearing on it continually ?... so far my test with webclient and httpwebrequest have not worked.

Comment: Would be good to post code of your current attempt (even though it does not work).

Comment: seems to be this exact case which seems to be unsolved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660773/how-to-listen-to-a-keep-alive-httpresponsemessage-until-its-closed

Comment: sample code
   MyWebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
   MyWebReq.Method = "GET";
   MyWebReq.KeepAlive = true;
   HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)MyWebReq.GetResponse();
   Stream receiveStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
 while (readStream.Peek() > -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadLine());
                    }
this works on the first read, but if i put it on a loop the subsequent reads don´t work.. (always null)

Comment: You are doing it almost correctly except that `Peek` - never use that. Try with `string line; while ((line = readStream.ReadLine()) != null) { Console.WriteLine(line); }`